# Add defer and ID attribute in cs cart auto generated complied javascript file

Tags: javascript, cs-cart

I am seeing that CS-CART compiling and combined javascript file as below:

```
<script src="http://localhost/cscart_v4143_b2b/var/cache/misc/assets/js/tygh/scripts-6e6a4b89efff9cd901a009c345e66db9.js?1650650345"></script>
```

I have two question:
1- How to add "id" and "defer" and "async" attribute?
2- From where location that file is compiling, combing and generating that above file?

Answer (score 1):

by default this file in end in the in the right place.
If you want improve google page speed, need to do another changes.
I have 6 years experience in cs cart cms and can you help with this.

If you really want to know where you can change this

1. templates/common/scripts.tpl tag {scripts}{/scripts} gather all js files and by hooks :)
2. here on backend drawning - ?432432423 - time param
   /public_html/app/functions/smarty_plugins/function.script.php

line - $src = Registry::get('config.current_location') . '/' . fn_link_attach($params['src'], 'ver=' . Tygh::$app['assets_cache_key']);

3. and 34 line you can add here - $scripts[$params['src']] = '<script'
   like this
   $scripts[$params['src']] = '<script defer async'